# How to disable buttons on the selected value of the other in AngularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, css, button, radio-button

I have two buttons - Company Email and Non Company Email.
If i select the first , ng-click="flag='Y'" and the second one renders the flag value as 'N'

So now I am trying to disable them when they are selected so user is not allowed to click on the second time, the second click is creating some UI issues which I want to avoid here.
But the ng-disabled is not working at all as expected, it disables from the outlook but we can still click the button and it behaves strangely.

Pleas help-
Code block is added in comments

Comment: <div class="form-group" ng-show="true" ng-class="{ 'has-error':submitted && SendEmailForm.togglebutton.$invalid}">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="togglebutton">    </label>
 <div class="btn-group btn-toggle col-xs-7" id="togglebutton" name="togglebutton" ng-model="flag" ng-init="flag=='Y'" >
 <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" ng-click="flag='Y'" ng-disabled="flag =='Y'" >Company EMAIL ID</button>
 <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active" ng-click="flag='N'" ng-disabled="flag=='N'">NON-Company EMAIL ID</button>
</div>

Comment: Did you solve your issue using my suggestion or are you still struggling?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple enough issue where you would disabled the buttons using a scope variable set once a button is clicked.

```
  <button ng-disabled="flag=='Y'" ng-click="doCompany()">Company Email</button>
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEs7fhAUYqi6TtPrrI1i?p=preview)

Comment: I added an alert to verify the click was not executing the 2nd time.  Re-factor to use my method and let me know

Comment: bmlSw - I did have this piece on my code already, if you see above on my code block you would see the following :

Comment: ng-click="flag='Y'" ng-disabled="flag =='Y'"

Comment: The problem is that it gets disabled but I can still click it, the button next to it should be the one enabled changes its color when the disabled one is clicked, also the disabled button's color changes when we click it although no action takes place. This is why I said the issue is very tricky and I posted the code too.

Comment: Could you create a plunkr example to demonstrate as i can not recreate the issue.

Comment: CLick on NON-Company EMAIL ID and the color stays on, it should get highlighted and the other button should be grayed which is not happening.  Plunker Link : http://plnkr.co/edit/b3ROZ5zsnB0lHxjV9DSQ

Comment: I updated my plunker to be more like your own. See http://plnkr.co/edit/g5I9vyPxbzywiNOFeLib

Your is missing a reference to the angular framework as well as 2 key directives

ng-app and ng-controller also you need to create your module and controller to initialize angular scope.

    angular.module('app', []).
       controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
         $scope.flag=''; 
      }]);